# Where de query usando multiplas propriedades de uma lista

Tags: c#, query, linq

Possuo o seguinte cenário

```
public Teste[] GetTestes(List<TesteDTO> testeDTOs){
    IQueryble<Teste> query = GetAll<Teste>();
    //where ... 

}   


public class Teste()
{
    public int Prop1{ get; set;}
    public int Prop2 { get; set;}
    public int Prop3 { get; set;}

    //outras props
}

public class TesteDTO(){
    public int Prop1{ get; set;}
    public int Prop2 { get; set;}
    public int Prop3 { get; set;}
}
```

No método `GetTestes` preciso aplicar um where na query, utilizando todas as propriedades de `TesteDTO`. Praticamente, garantir que a query só ira retornar `Testes` "iguais" as `TestesDTO` passadas como parametro no método.

Comment: Tenta ae: `query = query.Where(x => testeDTOs.Contains(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está caindo em uma questão de equalidade de classes diferentes. Para usar um `Contains` ou um `==`, é necessário que as duas classes tenham alguma forma de se comparar.

Para isso, crie um método que retorne `bool` dada uma comparação específica dentre as propriedades das classes.

```
public class A 
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }  
    public bool Igual(B b)
    {
        return  Prop1 == b.Prop1 && Prop2 == b.Prop2 && Prop3 == b.Prop3; //Aplique sua lógica de comparação entre as duas classes aqui
    }
}
public class B
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Tendo esse método, é possivel implementar a igualidade item-a-item:

```
List<A> lista = new List<A>(); //Recebe a lista inicial
List<A> listaFinal = new List<A>(); //Filtra a lista com os parâmetros 
List<B> listaComparacao = new List<B>(); //Lista de filtro recebida por parâmetro
listaFinal = lista.Where(a=>listaComparacao.Any(b=>a.Igual(b))).ToList();
```

O que o `.Where` última linha faz:

1) `a=>` Recebe no parâmetro com nome `a` a instância da classe `A` que existe na `lista`.

2) `listaComparacao.Any(b=>a.Igual(b))` Percorre a lista de comparação, verificando quais são "iguais" aos itens da lista inicial, executando o método de igualdade entre as duas classes.

Um ponto a ser notado: O método `Igual` não precisa existir dentro da classe `A`. Basta que esteja no visível no contexto do método que você vai filtrar.

### **EDIT**

Caso você não tenha a lista inicial, é possível realizar a filtragem em cima do `IQueriable`:

```
IQueryble<A> query = GetAll<A>();
List<A> listaFinal = new List<A>(); //Recebe a lista filtrada
List<B> listaComparacao = new List<B>(); //Lista de filtro recebida por parâmetro
listaFinal = query.Where(a=>listaComparacao.Any(b=>a.Igual(b))).ToList();
```

### **EDIT (2)**

Caso queira, é possível realizar uma comparação direta entre objetos das duas classes pelo operador `==`, fazendo um overload.

```
public class A 
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }  
    public bool Igual(B b)
    {
        return  Prop1 == b.Prop1 && Prop2 == b.Prop2 && Prop3 == b.Prop3; //Aplique sua lógica de comparação entre as duas classes aqui
    }
    public static bool operator ==(A a, B b)
    {
        return a.Igual(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(A a, B b)
    {
        return !a.Igual(b);
    }
}
```

Fazendo desta forma, é possível usar a query da seguinte forma:

```
IQueryble<A> query = GetAll<A>();
List<A> listaFinal = new List<A>(); //Recebe a lista filtrada
List<B> listaComparacao = new List<B>(); //Lista de filtro recebida por parâmetro
listaFinal = query.Where(a=>listaComparacao.Any(b=>a == b)).ToList();
```

Comment: A questão é que eu preciso fazer isso em uma query, que será executada no banco. Não posso trazer todos os registros da primeira lista para a memoria.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela alterei a resposta.